# Instantiating the class but declared as an interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Lets just say I have this interface and repository

**Interface :**

```
interface ICustomerRepository
    {
```

**Repository that implements the interface**

```
public class CustomerRepository:ICustomerRepository
    {
```

In controller, I declared an instance of the interface,

```
private ICustomerRepository repository = null;
```

can someone explain the concept of this line?

```
this.repository = new CustomerRepository();
```

Still learning here, need inputs.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: private ICustomerRepository repository = null; <-- this is declaring respository as an object of type ICustomerRepository.  this.repository = new CustomerRepository(); <-- This is assigning a default value to that variable, the default value of a new object of type ICustomerRepository.

Comment: @WDS thanks for the default value concept cheers!

Comment: it is called Polymorphism concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that particular scenario since `repository` is a placeholder for `ICustomerRepository` this would mean that you will only be able to access all members available from `ICustomerRepository`.

Consider the following:

```
interface ICustomerRepository
{
   void MethodB();
```

And then you implement it with this members:

```
public class CustomerRepository:ICustomerRepository
{      
   public void MethodA(){...} //Exclusive to CustomerRepository

   public void MethodB(){...} //CustomerRepository implements interface
```

When you use the `this.repository` only the members available from the interface is available such as:

```
this.repository.MethodB() //this is legal
```

but not

```
this.repository.MethodA() //this is illegal
```

because `MethodA` is part of `CustomerRepository`.

So you have to consider whether you want to isolate which members you would like to access. Is it only the group of members from the `interface` itself? Or you would also like to access other members inside the class of `CustomerRepository` which in some cases may also implement multiple interfaces like:

`CustomerRepository: ICustomerRepository, ICustomerRepository2, ICustomerRepository3` and so on.

So to make it short the line below only allows you to access the members implemented inside `CustomerRepository` which is agreed upon the contract of  `ICustomerRepository`.

```
//Get only members defined inside `ICustomerRepository`
//This can be properties or methods
this.repository = new CustomerRepository();
```

To validate your question in your comment see the following:

```
ICustomerRepository repository = new CustomerRepository();

//Yields true repository is instance of ICustomerRepository
Console.WriteLine(typeof(ICustomerRepository).IsInstanceOfType(repository));

//Yields true repository is instance of CustomerRepository
Console.WriteLine(typeof(CustomerRepository).IsInstanceOfType(repository));

CustomerRepository repository2 = new CustomerRepository();

//Yields true repository2 is instance of ICustomerRepository
Console.WriteLine(typeof(ICustomerRepository).IsInstanceOfType(repository2));

//Yields true repository2 is instance of CustomerRepository
Console.WriteLine(typeof(CustomerRepository).IsInstanceOfType(repository2));
```

All yields true so you would see that an instance of `repository` is an instance of type of both `ICustomerRepository` and `CustomerRepository`.

Comment: does this mean that `CustomerRepository` is an instance of `ICustomerRepository`? coz its allowed to instantiate the interface to a class the implements it, in this case `CustomerRepository`

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi did you mean `repository` being an instance of both? If it is then yes. You can see it on the additional solution above for validation.

Comment: Enriquez, i get it now, salamat